# How come my Bootstrap Pills dropdown won't work?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I basically copied the components of a Pills dropdown menu from http://getbootstrap.com/components/ but it simply won't work. When I click the menu item, the dropdown just doesn't appear. I copied my exact code into a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/j63f0o2f/. Snippet from the JSFiddle:

```
<div class="nav">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
        <li><a href="#">Robot Technology</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Webdesign <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li><a href="#">HTML 5</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">CSS 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Bootstrap 5</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
```

Comment: Did you add the Bootstrap JavaScript files?

Comment: Snippet from my head:
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to insert the Bootstrap JavaScript file and the JQuery JavaScritp file within the `<head>` tag. Have a closer look at the following code snippet:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
        <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
    <div class="nav">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
        <li><a href="#">Robot Technology</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Webdesign <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li><a href="#">HTML 5</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">CSS 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Bootstrap 5</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
  </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I included your example header in my header, and now it works. I have been struggling with this for so long, so you have all my thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You probably havent included the bootstrap.js and jquery.js at the bottom of the body with `<script src=""></script>`

https://jsfiddle.net/j63f0o2f/1/